# Why would it be in Russia's interests if the Nord Stream 1 was left unoperational?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, nord-stream

Supply through **NordStream-1** is [disrupted](https://youtu.be/ShXmPA21j-E). Accusations were made that Russia was responsible for it. If Russia indeed was responsible for it, how would that be in Russia's interest?

- Destroying its own source of income (and a very lucrative one at that), seems a bit counter-productive.
- Also, **NordStream-1** could have been a negotiating card for pursuing peace, which is now permanently closed.